# SQL Server pivot does not group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, adventureworks

I am reading the prep kit for MS exam 70-461 : Querying MS SQL Server 2012 and the author talks about the `PIVOT` operator. I am using the AdventureWorks sample database to make tests.

I decided to do a simple test and see if I could present the average base rate per department on columns split for each gender (M, F).

I have the following:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        [DepartmentName], 
        [Gender], 
        [BaseRate] 
    FROM 
        [AdventureWorks].[dbo].[DimEmployee]
)

SELECT
    [DepartmentName], [M], [F]
FROM 
    [AdventureWorks].[dbo].[DimEmployee] PIVOT (Avg(BaseRate) FOR [Gender] IN ([M], [F])) AS P
```

However, I noticed this:

There are no groups on `[DepartmentName]` as should be (according to the book) since it's the only field not specified in the `PIVOT` operator.

I can add a simple GROUP BY clause but I am not sure that this would yield the appropriate result and this also means that I did not correctly understand the use of PIVOT.

Any idea where I am wrong ?

Comment: Just a small question: why do you need a CTE here?

Comment: The book says it's to set up the aggregating fields for the PiVOT operator.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur - But you forgot to `SELECT` from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define the CTE but then ignore it and select from the base table anyway.

It should be

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT [DepartmentName],
                [Gender],
                [BaseRate]
         FROM   [AdventureWorks].[dbo].[DimEmployee])
SELECT [DepartmentName],
       [M],
       [F]
FROM   CTE PIVOT (Avg(BaseRate) FOR [Gender] IN ([M], [F])) AS P
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT
[DepartmentName], [Gender], [BaseRate]
FROM 
[AdventureWorks].[dbo].[DimEmployee] PIVOT (Avg(BaseRate) FOR [Gender] IN ([M], [F])) AS P
```